# How can I configure Compass and Zurb Foundation 5 in my Rails 4 app so that they are both accessible in the same directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I have a Rails 4 app in which I am using Compass and Zurb Foundation 5.  I would like to use both Compass and Foundation 5 with a Rails 4 app.

More specifically, I want to be able to do this in a stylesheet.scss file:

```
@import "compass";
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
[additional imports]
```

In other words, I want to be able to have all my sass files in the same directory. However, currently, Foundation scss files lives in 'app/assets/stylesheets' because it appears that the Foundation file 'foundation_and_overrides.scss' needs to live in this directory.  At the same time, I have all my other sass files in a '/sass' directory, which then are compiled to 'app/assets/stylesheets'

How can I configure Compass and/or Foundation so that they are all accessible from the same directory?

**It seems it is just a question of knowing the correct path to use for my import.**

As per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256274/configuring-zurb-foundation-sass-with-compass-how-do-you-get-it-working-and-us) I attempted the following:

```
@import 'foundation/foundation-global';
@import 'foundation/components/type';
```

However, then I get the following compass error:

```
    error sass/stylesheet.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation.
    Load paths:
      /Users/Anders/Dropbox/WWW/sbox-project/research/foundation-test/sass
      /Users/Anders/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.4/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
      /Users/Anders/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/compass-0.12.4/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
      Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

#### Gem versions in use:

- compass (0.12.4)
- compass-rails (1.1.7)
- foundation-rails (5.2.1.0)

#### Compass config file (compass.rb)

```
    project_type = :rails
    http_path = "/"
    css_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets"
    sass_dir = "sass"
    images_dir = "app/assets/images"
    javascripts_dir = "app/assets/javascripts"
```

Any advice would be appreciated!  Also, please let me know what additional information I should provide to offer advice on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you run 'rails g foundation:install' after your bundle install?

Comment: Yup, followed these instructions http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html

Answer (score 0):

in compass.rb

```
sass_dir = 'app/assets/stylesheets'
```

it's also better to have compiled css files in the 'public' folder.

```
css_dir = 'public/stylesheets'
images_dir = 'public/images'
javascripts_dir = 'public/javascripts'
fonts_dir = 'public/fonts'
```

then init compass :

```
compass init
```

or if using bundler :

```
bundle exec compass init
```

your config/compass.rb changes will then be applied to config.rb